# Problem with Angle Between Two Vectors Proof

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I am trying to prove the angle between two vectors (u and v) formula i.e. $$u\cdot v = \cos(\theta)\|u\|\|v\|$$
I am having problem figuring out only a part of the proof. Please refer to the image from the proof of the formula as given in the book Mathematics for Economists by Simon and Blume.

In the image, m is given to be equal to $u - tv$. I am not sure which property is being used. I don't think the Pythagoras theorem is being used. Can anyone help explain what this is concerned with.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It's vector addition. Aside from the parallelogram method you can add them by placing the tail of one on the head of the other. In this case, you should be able to see that $tv+(u-tv)=u$. The scalar $t$ is used to adjust the length of $v$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\cos(\theta) = \frac{OR}{OP}$, where $OR = ||tv||$, $OP = ||u||$.

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos(\theta) &= \frac{||tv||}{||u||} = \frac{|t|\cdot||v||}{||u||}\Leftrightarrow ||u||\cos(\theta) = |t|\cdot||v|| \Leftrightarrow \\
|t|||v||^2 &= ||u||||v||\cos(\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$

Next, applying the Pythagorean theorem, $OR^2 = OP^2-RP^2$, i.e.,

$$
\begin{aligned}
t^2||v||^2 &= ||u||^2-||u-tv||^2 = u\cdot u - (u-tv)\cdot (u-tv) = \\
&= u\cdot u - u\cdot u + 2t u \cdot v - t^2v\cdot v = 2t u \cdot v - t^2||v||^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
2t^2 ||v||^2 &= 2t u \cdot v \Leftrightarrow t||v||^2 = u\cdot v
\end{aligned}
$$

Comparing the two equalities, we obtained that
$$
u\cdot v = ||u||||v||\cos(\theta)
$$